# What could be causing a 400 Bad Request error in PhpMyAdmin under Plesk on Ubuntu 20.04.6?

Tags: phpmyadmin, plesk

we are using Plesk in the company on an Ubuntu 20.04.6. One of our employees regularly receives the following error:
`Error while processing the request Error code: 400 Error text: Bad Request (rejected)`

Under `/var/log/plesk/httpsd_access_log` I could find the request with the HTTP 400 code, but I could not reproduce it.
`*IP RETRACTED* - - [02/Jun/2023:13:32:44 +0200] "GET /phpMyAdmin/index.php?route=/table/search&db=*DB RETRACTED*&table=*TABLE RETRACTED*&ajax_request=true&ajax_page_request=true&_nocache=1685705564547799363&token=*TOKEN RETRACTED* HTTP/1.1" 400 5 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/113.0" "-"'/phpMyAdmin/index.php' '' '/usr/local/psa'`

The auth.log also contains the following error with the corresponding IP address of the user.
`./auth.log:Jun 2 13:35:03 websrv phpMyAdmin[927444]: user denied: (empty-denied) from *IP RETRACTED*`

Unfortunately, I don't know what to do and I can't find a similar case among the errors mentioned above. In the attached photo, I unfortunately had to make some things unrecognisable.
[screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohsL7.png)

- PhpMyAdmin Version: 5.2.1
- PHP Version: 8.0.28
- Plesk Version: Plesk Obsidian v18.0.51_build1800230404.10 os_Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurs when the connection of the Plesk GUI login times out. It also times out the phpMyAdmin connection. You could change the timeout value in Tools & Settings > Security > Session Idle Time to accomodate longer breaks.

Comment: That would explain it. The employee logs in via Plesk, but then only works in PhpMyAdmin and not in Plesk. The timeout will obviously only be reset when there is activity in Plesk. Thank you!